# Blackberry: how to catch system event?

Tags: blackberry

Can we catch in code moment when user execute "switch application" action?

Comment: give us a clear idea. I think you want to run indirectly the "switch application" option in the menu;

Comment: Yes, as a case. Also it can be executed via off button.

Comment: it can be executed via off button. what is the meaning of this? you can run the "Menu Options(like switchApplication)" indirectly from your code when ever you want;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When switching applications, your `UiApplication`'s `activate()` method is invoked when your application comes to the foreground and `deactivate()` is called when it goes to background.

Comment: Thanks, Vlad. It is what I want.